# Javascript : How to hide multiple generated div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `class="slip line_{{lineIndex}}` and its generating multiple divs with different numbers and i need a javascript to select a div with specific class.

```
{{#generateLottoRoomLines}}
<div id="tickett_" data-type="slip" data-slip-index="{{lineIndex}}" class="slip line_{{lineIndex}}" class="lottoroom_yourTicket-content_tickets" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I need a example not a book to read or tutorials. Or the code and i'll read it and maybe ill understand it. But it's my second question here. So please help me guys!

Comment: Ok try please to explain more clearly what you need to achieve.

Comment: <div id="tickett_" data-type="slip" data-slip-index="{{lineIndex}}" class="slip line_{{lineIndex}}" class="lottoroom_yourTicket-content_tickets" >

I mess up my code. Here in this example i have this class="slip line_{{lineIndex}} and its generating multiple divs with different numbers and i need a javascript to select a div with specific class. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Not in comments but edit the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery selector:

```
$(".slip.line_" + lineIndex)
```

Note: to find an element with multiple CSS-classes use this format:

```
$(".first-class.second-class.third-class")
```

In your case if you don't have CSS-classes like 'line_{{lineIndex}}' in other places of your page you can just use the following selector to find required div:

```
$(".line_" + lineIndex)
```

Or

```
$("div.line_" + lineIndex)
```

**Update:**
Your HTML is incorrect:

```
class="slip line_{{lineIndex}}" class="lottoroom_yourTicket-content_tickets"
```

You have multiple class-attributes. You should combine them:

```
class="lottoroom_yourTicket-content_tickets slip line_{{lineIndex}}"
```